# Calculating the recursive "n" number

Tags: python, recursion, python-2.x

I am teaching my self python 2 at the moment using exercise books. I am currently studying recursive function. I am a bit confused how the "n" value is calculated. Below as a simple example I have created for myself.

```
def input(x, y, n):  
    if n == 0:
        return
    print (x + y), "Recurse no.", n
    input(x, y, n - 1)

    print (x + 1), "Recurse no.", n
    input(x, y, n - 1)

input(10, 6, 3)
```

| Result | Recurse number |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | Recurse no. 3 |
| 16 | Recurse no. 2 |
| 16 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 2 |
| 16 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 3 |
| 16 | Recurse no. 2 |
| 16 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 2 |
| 16 | Recurse no. 1 |
| 11 | Recurse no. 1 |

I have tried to work out the "n" manually as below be but nor sure how it woks after the first 3 rows.

[manual working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABt8W.png)

I would be grateful if someone can explain how after n = 3 2 1 is worked out.

Comment: Please, format your code correctly

Comment: I believe you did not copy-paste your code correctly? Right now it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: May I ask why you want to learn Python2 and not Python3?

Comment: Indentation is very important in Python.  Your code is not indented correctly.

Comment: Sorry. It's my first time posting. I have fixed the indentation. My excel was my manual working to illustrate the "n" being passed through the calls. Thanks again.

Comment: what is the confusion regarding the n variable?

Comment: The n variable keeps on decreasing on each recusrive call and when it reaches 0 it doesnt print anything

Comment: Are you aware that Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since 2 years and that this was announced over 10 years ago?

Comment: @Albin Paul. Thank you for your quick reply. In my example, it calls on the "input" function twice. I can understand the n value 3 pass through the (n - 1) until 0. hence it returns 16 (10+6) 3 times. But what about the second "input" call. which n number does it uses as the result is showing 11 twice. I presume the second call does not start from 3 again?

Comment: In your function you call `input(x, y, n - 1)` two times. You don't change `x`, `y` and `n` between those calls so they are the same for each call.

Comment: Why do you presume that? The value of `n` is never on the left-hand side of an assignment, so it doesn’t change within a given level of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the left portion to see the recursion call stack.
The input function is called 4 times.
And when the function returns after completing the function or encountering the return 0 statement, the function is removed from the call stack.

So regarding your question. The variables that you use, are stored on the stack along side the function itself.

In the below eample if I click the first function call, I will see n=3.
and if I click second one, I will see n=2, etc.

[image: call stack and values]

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change to your function to see more easily what happens

```
def input(x, y, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    print (x + y, "A Recurse no.", n)
    input(x, y, n - 1)

    print (x + 1, "B Recurse no.", n)
    input(x, y, n - 1)

input(10, 6, 3)
```

output :

```
16 A Recurse no. 3
16 A Recurse no. 2
16 A Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 2
16 A Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 3
16 A Recurse no. 2
16 A Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 2
16 A Recurse no. 1
11 B Recurse no. 1
```

So after 3,2,1 your input is called with input(10,6,0) so it return without printing anything and the second part can be executed.